# Install to, Install on...?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

No replacement parts will be installed to your car.
No replacement parts will be installed on your car.
No replacement parts will be installed onto your car.

Which one of these is correct? I'm not sure when to use install to/on/onto

Answer (score 2):

The trick to the word install, is it depends on the context you are using the word. We commonly think of the word install in the context of computer software. In this context we would say:

*"I installed the new software program **on** my computer."*

According to the dictionary, the definition of the word for the context that you are using it is:

> Install - to place or fix (equipment or machinery) in position ready
>   for use.

To determine which word to use after install, when using it in this context, depends on the location (position) the part that was installed.

For example, your sentence is referring to a part inside the car. In this case, it would be best to say that the part was installed **in or inside**. This is because we are specifically referring to the positional arrangement of the actual component and referring to where it is located. In your case, it would be more appropriate to say:

*"The mechanic installed the replacement part in the car."*

We are implying that the part was positioned inside of the car and is now ready for use (from our reporting sentence).

If instead the component was installed on the dash board, then you would report its location similarly. *"The part was installed on your car's dashboard."*

Essentially, you are just reporting the location where the part was actual installed. Inside, on, on top of, etc.

When talking about things like software, we are talking about the definition:

> Install - to load software onto a computer.

In this case it is often installed on. For example, *a new version of the operating system was installed on my phone* **not** *a new version of the operating system was installed in my phone*.